# How to pass an Error to a function in jasmine/jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, jasmine2.0

I have the following test code:

```
it('throws a `TypeError`', () => {
  expect(() => {
    // For context:
    //   The second argument to this method MUST be an Error instance
    //   The second argument to this method MUST be a String
    this.myClass.error(new Error(), {});
  }).toThrow(new TypeError('`message` must be a String'));
});
```

However, when it is run, the `new Error()` call throws an uncaught exception at that moment (not failing the test, but blowing up my console).

How can I pass the function an `Error` instance that doesn't throw when it's created? Specifically, whatever is passed (lets call it `x`), needs to be able to pass the test `x instanceof Error`.